# Outlook Sent Items Gone from Archive?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a user whose Sent Items folder is empty, in their Archive folder..  Is there a way this could have happened other than the user accidentally deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

It could happen if he didnt select the sent items to be archived.

Answer (score 0):

**Outlook 2003**

1. On the original mailbox, **right-click** on their Sent Items folder
2. Go to **Properties**
3. Click on the **Auto Archive** tab
4. Make sure their settings are comparable to what you'd expect to see in the Archived PST

Answer (score 0):

8 years on, evidently this problem has not gone away, as I've just been hit by it on a machine using Outlook 2013.

I was able to fix the problem using MFCMAPI. This tool is on GitHub, and there's a good article [here](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/delete-outlooks-default-folders/) showing how to set the necessary attributes. 
Once I ran MFCMAPI, I could see that the Sent Items folder was actually present in the archive, just not visible in Outlook. Using the steps in the linked article, I was able to restore the proper visibility.

[image]

In my case, Sent Items didn't have the PR_ATTR_HIDDEN attribute initially, but after following the steps to add PR_ATTR_HIDDEN to hide a folder, and then in a second step setting it to false, Sent Items became visible.

*NB there seems to be some caching as I then had to remove and re-add the archive in Outlook's list of data files in the left pane before Sent Items became visible.*